# Hibernate: How to decide on Entity Type and Value Type objects

Tags: hibernate, entity, hibernate-mapping, value-type

Is it correct that if you want to access the state of an object directly, you should make that object an Entity Type object but you want to access an object through a reference you should make it an Value Type object?

Could some help me understand Entity Type and Value Type objects in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Entity bean has its **own identity** and it can be **independent** and it has its **own life cycle**.whereas value type bean does not have its own identity. Meaning it always depends on it's holder bean for reference.Also it does not have its own life cycle.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Entity object and Value object have different context. Please have look on this doc
[[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/bc_awhatisaneo.htm]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/bc_awhatisaneo.htm%5d)